# HERE MAPS MSDKUI

Tags: here-api

I downloaded the MSDKUI kit that Here Maps created (https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios).

I have one issue though, the distance and guidance maneuver measurements are all showing in feet, yards, and miles (which is what they call imperial measurements in their standard SDK). However in the USA we don’t use yards, we just miles and feet. This is demonstrated properly in the regular HereMaps SDK functionality that I have been using for a long time where the voice prompts do talk in US units. I do that by specifying navigationManager.voicePackageMeasurementSystem = .imperialUS.

My question is how can I get the display that shows distance to maneuvers and all of that information that is now built in to the MSKUI Kit as well, to also show as imperialUS in miles and feet not yards?  I have searched through the documentation and cannot find anything with the spelling of ImperialUS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `distanceFormatter` property (for example it exist in `GuidanceManeuverView` class, might be called similar on other components) to replace default implementation.

This is [`MeasurementFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter) class from Foundation, so I believe you can setup it as you want (e.g. set specific locale - en_US - for imperialUS units).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I see many instances of  formatter.locale = .current etc. in many classes. Where does it get the locale from? the device? the device says English US. Where can I change the actual locale?

Comment: `.current` means region that is currently set on the device. So UI is adapting based on device configuration (can be checked and set iOS settings). For details please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale